# Toggling the `spell` option with Lua does not redraw the screen until an additional command is entered

Tags: neovim, spell-checking, options

While porting my `init.vim` to `init.lua`, I noticed some strange behaviour.

In vimscript, one can toggle `spell` in the following way:

```vimscript
noremap <Leader>ss :setlocal spell!<CR>
```

Observe that this keymap involves entering command mode, then returning to normal mode.

When porting this to Lua, the most direct translation method works identically:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("", "<Leader>ss", ":setlocal spell!<CR>")
```

However, for the sake of easier-to-read code, I want to set the `spell` option using the Lua table of values instead.

```lua
function ToggleSpell()
        vim.wo.spell = not vim.wo.spell
        print("spell is " .. tostring(vim.wo.spell))
end

vim.keymap.set("", "<Leader>ss", ToggleSpell, { expr = true, })
```

Now when I type `<Leader>ss`, a message is printed telling me the state of `spell`, but the highlighting of misspelled words does not change until I type an additional command (e.g., a motion command, or entering insert mode. Interestingly, entering command mode does not trigger the spelling highlighting until returning to normal mode).

Inlining the function does not change this behaviour:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("", "<Leader>st", function ()
        vim.wo.spell = not vim.wo.spell
end, { expr = true, })
```

Note that running the function directly on the commandline

```vimscript
:lua ToggleSpell()
```

*does* result in the highlighting to toggle immediately (perhaps because of the return from command mode to normal mode).

When setting an option in Lua, should I be calling a screen redraw myself? Is there a canonical way of triggering a screen redraw in this case without changing modes?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an explicit `:redraw` will solve the problem, and seems to be the standard practice for those writing low-level plugins. (See [this similar discussion for `:highlight`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/18160) which recommends using `:redraw[!]`.)

```lua
function ToggleSpell()
        vim.wo.spell = not vim.wo.spell
        vim.cmd("redraw")
        print("spell is " .. tostring(vim.wo.spell))
end
```

The big question comes down to whether this actually improves readability. One may argue that `:setlocal spell!<CR>` more clearly communicates that this mapping toggles spelling in the local window than the function name `ToggleSpell`. One possible refactor is to rename it to `ToggleLocalSpell`, or to pass in the scope directly:

```lua
function ToggleSpell(scope)
        return function ()
                scope.spell = not scope.spell
                vim.cmd("redraw")
                print("spell is " .. tostring(scope.spell))
        end
end

vim.keymap.set("", "<Leader>ss", ToggleSpell(vim.wo), { expr = true, })
```

Now it is explicitly clear that the local option is for the *window* and not the buffer.